# Are disk_io_counters accumulative

Tags: python, python-3.x, psutil

I'm using `psutils` to get disk information and I'm wondering a bit more about `disk_io_counters()`. Are the numbers that come back each time I make that call accumulative? Or is it the delta between the last time I called it and now? Something else? I've read [the docs here](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#disks) and they don't provide much detail in terms of what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, those counters get their data from the `/proc/diskstats` file. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt for more. They are cumulative and reset when they overflow or the disk that they pertain to is removed or when the computer resets. I can't find a source to support that last statement but it is true.